# Pthread program returning expected declaration specifiers or â...â before â&â token

Tags: linux, pthreads, semaphore

I am getting the same error multiple times when compiling the following `pthreads` program in `linux` using:

gcc -c -lpthread proj2_part1.c -lrt

```
    #include <unistd.h>     
    #include <sys/types.h>  
    #include <errno.h>      
    #include <stdio.h>      
    #include <stdlib.h>     
    #include <pthread.h>    
    #include <string.h>     
    #include <semaphore.h>  
    #define BUFFER_SIZE 10
    #define TRUE 1

    struct cQueue{
    int *buffer;
    int front, rear;
    }*queue;

    int count;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex; 
    sem_t full, empty; 

    ........
    /*MAIN*/
    int main(int argc,char* argv[])
    {
         int a=0, b=0, count =0, buff[BUFFER_SIZE];
         int p = atoi(argv[1]), c = atoi(argv[2]);
         unsigned int s = atoi(argv[0]);
         pthread_t prothread[p], conthread[c];

         /*Initialize Semaphores*/
         if (sem_init(&full,0,0) == -1)
          printf("%s\n",strerror(errno));

 if (sem_init(&empty,0,BUFFER_SIZE) == -1)
          printf("%s\n",strerror(errno));

 pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);

 /*Initialize Circular Queue*/
 queue->buffer=buff;
 queue->front = queue->buffer[0];
 queue->rear = queue->buffer[0];

 if(argc!=3)
 {
      fprintf(stderr,"Syntax: ./a.out <int> <int> <int>");
      return -1;
 }
 if(s<0)
 {
      fprintf(stderr,"Argument %d must be positive value\n",s);
      return -1;
 }
 else
 {
   /*Create producer threads*/
   int i;
   for (i=0; i<p; i++)
   {   
    b = pthread_create(&prothread[i], NULL, producerThread, (void*)argv[1]);
     if (b<0)
     {
     printf("Error: unable to create thread, %d\n",b);
     return -1;
     }
   }
  /*Create consumer threads*/
 int j;
 for (j=0; j<c; j++)
 (
     a = pthread_create(&conthread[j], NULL, consumerThread, (void*)argv[2]);
     if (a<0)
        {
        printf("Error: unable to create thread, %d\n",a);
        return -1;
        }
 }     
 sleep(atoi(argv[0]));
 }
 return 0;
 }
```

I am receiving the following error. I think it has something to do with my semaphore declaration.

```
    proj2_part1.c:147:81: error: expected â)â before â;â token
          a = pthread_create(&conthread[j], NULL, consumerThread, (void*)argv[2]);
                                                                                 ^
        proj2_part1.c:153:6: error: expected â;â before â}â token}     
                                                                ^
        proj2_part1.c: At top level:
        proj2_part1.c:156:6: error: expected identifier or â(â before âreturnâ
      return 0;
      ^
        proj2_part1.c:157:1: error: expected identifier or â(â before â}â token
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've used a `(` where you meant `{`:

```
for (j=0; j<c; j++)
(
```

Comment: TYVM. I am ashamed to say how long I looked for that. I shouldn't be programming so late